# AWS Nodejs cannot connect to RDS MariaDb instance with IAM authentication through Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mariadb, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I have troubling connecting to my MariaDb instance on RDS, it works when I'm using only the database credentials with the setting *Password and IAM database authentication* disabled.

But when I try to use IAM authentication with a token from RDS Signer, while running the file locally with node, I get the following error:

```
Access denied for user 'interactive_rds_user'@'<my_ip_address>' (using password: NO)
```

When running the Lambda, I get the following error:

```
CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
```

I also tried connecting with the same user as before through MySQL CLI locally which worked, I even tried it with the Signer token from the nodejs code.

I have checked multiple times that all the environment variables are correct, the IAM policy is correct & IAM role is correct.

Here's my nodejs file:

```
const { Signer } = require("@aws-sdk/rds-signer");
const mariadb = require("mariadb");

const getDbPool = async () => {
  /** @type {import('@aws-sdk/rds-signer').SignerConfig} */
  const signerOptions = {
    region: "eu-west-1",
    hostname: process.env.InteractiveInvoice,
    port: 3306,
    username: process.env.InteractiveInvoiceDbUser
  };

  const rdsSigner = new Signer(signerOptions);
  const rdsToken = await rdsSigner.getAuthToken();

  /** @type {mariadb.PoolConfig} */
  const mariadbConfig = {
    host: process.env.InteractiveInvoice,
    port: 3306,
    user: process.env.InteractiveInvoiceDbUser,
    password: rdsToken,
    database: process.env.InteractiveInvoiceDb
  };

  return mariadb.createPool(mariadbConfig);
};

module.exports = {
  getDbPool
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added sufficient permission to your lambda IAM role? Refer this for more detail - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html